# what is a wireless channel and the pratical difference between then?

Tags: telecommunication, wireless

I was studying about differences in  2,4 GHz and 5 GHz , i could understand  the whole concept about speed,  the range, the frequency etc...
 But I still can understand what is a channel. I got some definitions but doesn't  make sense " a wireless channel is a way to fine tune  and alter the frequency " Could someone explain please.

Answer (score 1):

The channels are just an agreed way to refer to different regions within the portion of bandwidth for a particular wifi range.

For example, each channel in the 2.4GHz spectrum is 5 MHz from the next one - or more accurately the 'centre' of the channels are that distance apart. See below for a diagram from Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels):

[image]

Its important to note that WiFI needs a certain range each side of the centre frequency of the channels (which again are simply a shorthand for specific frequencies within the range), This is shown above and its easy to see from this how channels can 'overlap' which is a common term used in WiFi also.